# How to implement overarching interface over different class types

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm trying to implement an interface with some basic functionality to modify BIOS settings from multiple computer vendors.

So far, I've got the following:

```
public interface IBiosConfigurator
{
    bool IsBiosPasswordSet();

    bool ValidateBiosPassword(string password);

    bool SetBiosPassword(string currentPassword, string newPassword);

    T GetSetting<T>(string settingName, string password);

    T GetSetting<T>(string settingName, string propertyName, string password);

    bool SetSetting<T>(string settingName, T value, string password);
}
```

However I quickly figured out this sort of falls short of what I need:

- If something does fail, I have no idea why. Was it a bad password? Is the value you're trying to set not allowed? Does the setting name not exist?
- Each manufacturer has their own way of showing errors: some use ints, others uints, others strings, there's no common type.
- Even methods as simple as `bool IsBiosPasswordSet()` have a chance of failing, and it's not accounting for that.

The only way I can think of mitigating the fact that each manufacturer has their own way of setting errors (and different errors per vendor) is creating an `enum BiosErrorCode` and try to match vendor codes to a list I maintain on each class implementing `IBiosConfigurator`.

But I still need to return the actual error code that something produced and while this seems ok to me as far as a method declaration goes:

```
BiosErrorCode GetSetting<T>(string settingName, string password, out T value)
```

I can't really say the same for:

```
BiosErrorCode IsBiosPasswordSet(out bool passwordSet);
```

But the only other way I can think of solving this is a property `BiosErrorCode LastErrorCode` which would allow me to keep my methods declaration as they are, but feels a bit like PInvokes ...

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Can anyone think of a better way of doing this?
2. If not, which is more appropriate, the usage of `out params` or a `BiosErrorCode` property?

Comment: Have a look at `Try` and `Option` monads. Their appropriate use can help you better manage the failure situations as well as the cases where you have to represent an optional result.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the word `Bios` is redundant. ;) More on the serious side: I would argue that if somethings goes wrong you throw a custom exception. Under normal circumstances your implementations should just return what you expect. So if that is not the case it is truly exceptional, and that is what exceptions are for.

It allows you to hide the vendor specific logic to create those exceptions to the vendor specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In Solid principle, a class or an interface should not cover a lot of unrelated businesses in one object.

Comment: How is it unrelated?

Comment: In my opinion, I should seperate  2 interfaces, one is configuration, one is to validate. In future, if I want to add another method which wants to configurate something, I will put it in interface configuration. This is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If things fail then throw standardised exceptions in the concrete classes (e.g. InvalidPasswordException), with the details being implementation specific, rather than trying to use return codes or out vars. You can include much more detail in an exception and your calling program can handle them in a more structured fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw an exception if anything goes wrong. Conceptually the Exceptions live with your Interfcae and you should never throw anything that is not mentioned in the Interface documentation.

This leaves one avenue of issues open, the one that is poorly captured in an Exception. For those you should have a logging implementation where the implementing class gets a logger at contruction time passed in and traces out all the technical details that you may need later. It is common to just write to console since this can be easily redirected. There are more interesing frameworks for logging, The implementing class should get a logger as an interface that has strong nothrow guarantees.

It really comes down to your documentation in most cases.

Here is an example:

```
public class PasswordExpection : Exception
{
    public PasswordExpection(string msg) : base(msg) { }
}

public class BiosExpection : Exception
{
    public BiosExpection(string msg, Exception inner) : base(msg, inner) { }
}

interface IBiosControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a password is set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="PasswordExpection">if the concept of password does not apply</exception>
    /// <exception cref="BiosExpection">if there was an execution error</exception>
    /// <returns>Weather or not the password was set</returns>
    bool IsPasswordSet();
}

public class MyBios : IBiosControl
{
    private readonly Action<string> _logger;

    public MyBios(Action<string> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public bool IsPasswordSet()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger("MyBios IsPasswordSet Connecting To Bios...");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new BiosExpection("Execution Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```